# Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства Chunk.generate() требуется ссылка на объект

Tags: unity3d, static

Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства Chunk.generate() требуется ссылка на объект.
Я хотел сделать так что бы из 1го скрипта:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TerrainMain : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        Chunk.GEN();
    }
}
```

Запускалась функция GEN. которая уже и выполняет дальнейшие действия во 2м скрипте:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chunk : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject currentBlockType;

    public float smooth = 0;
    public float multiplier = 0;
    public int cols = 50;
    public int rows = 50;
    public bool CombineChunk;

    private Vector3 myPos;
    private Transform thisObject;

    static private GameObject thisobjscr;

    private void Start()
    {
        thisobjscr = gameObject;
        thisObject = gameObject.transform;
    }
    public static void GEN()
    {
        generate();
    }

    public void generate()
    {
        myPos = this.transform.position;

        for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < rows; z++)
            {
                float y = Mathf.PerlinNoise((myPos.x + x) / smooth, (myPos.z + z) / smooth) * multiplier;
                y = Mathf.Floor(y);

                GameObject newBlock = GameObject.Instantiate(currentBlockType);
                newBlock.transform.position = new Vector3(myPos.x + x, y, myPos.z + z);
                newBlock.transform.SetParent(thisObject);

                if (CombineChunk == true)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(TimerForCombineWait());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator TimerForCombineWait()
    {
        CombineChunk = false;
        print("waiting for world stabilization: " + Time.time);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        print("world stabilized in " + Time.time);
        Combine();
    }

    public void Combine()
    {
        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];

        int a = 0;
        while (a < meshFilters.Length)
        {
            combine[a].mesh = meshFilters[a].sharedMesh;
            combine[a].transform = meshFilters[a].transform.localToWorldMatrix;

            meshFilters[a].gameObject.SetActive(false);

            a++;
        }
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = new Mesh();
        transform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh.CombineMeshes(combine);
        transform.gameObject.SetActive(true);

        gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Unity выдает ошибку 
как раз в public static void GEN

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статический метод `public static void GEN()` вызывает нестатический метод `public void generate()`, что, очевидно, не будет работать.

Не совсем понятно, чего вы хотели добиться дополнительной статической оберткой над обычным методом - компилятор не обманешь ;)